# How do I remove the background image when I click on another button?

Tags: javascript

I have 4 links:

```
<tr class="imglinks">
    <td id="tab-title-1" class="button">
        <a href="#" class="tb_label" onclick="onShowTab(1)"><img src="form_includes/room-button_01.png"/></a>
    </td>

    <td id="tab-title-2" class="button">
        <a href="#" class="tb_label" onclick="onShowTab(2)"><img src="form_includes/room-button_02.png"/></a>
    </td>

    <td id="tab-title-3" class="button">
        <a href="#" class="tb_label" onclick="onShowTab(3)"><img src="form_includes/room-button_03.png"/></a>
    </td>

    <td id="tab-title-4" class="button">
        <a href="#" class="tb_label" onclick="onShowTab(4)"><img src="form_includes/room-button_04.png"/></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and when I click on each of the images it replaces the background image with pressed.png but when I click on another image the background images stays on the first image.

[image]

The JavaScript that handles the background is:

```
function onShowTab(index) {
    var numberTabs = 4;
    for (var i = 1; i < (numberTabs + 1); i++) {

        var tabTitle = document.getElementById('tab-title-' + i);
        tabTitle.style.backgroundColor = "";
        tabTitle.style.borderBottom = "";

        var tabSheet = document.getElementById('tab-sheet-' + i);
        tabSheet.style.display = "none";
    }

    var tabTitle = document.getElementById('tab-title-' + index);
    tabTitle.style.background = "#f3f3f3 url('form_includes/pressed.png') no-repeat right top"
    tabTitle.style.borderBottom = "0px";

    var tabSheet = document.getElementById('tab-sheet-' + index);
    tabSheet.style.display = "block";

}
```

my overall goal for this is for the image background to change to the pressed image thus to indicate what section your in.

Comment: that is not javacode that's javascript, there is a huge difference between both.

Answer (score 0):

You only clear the background color of all images before setting the image on the current (clicked) button. You need to remove the background image as well (or the complete background).

For your info: you can use document.querySelectorAll() with a classname selector to get all buttons at once instead of looping through an index and do a getElementById() on each one.

Comment: how would I clear it so it wont repeat the image for each of the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

```
function onShowTab(index) {
    var numberTabs = 4;
    for (var i = 1; i < (numberTabs + 1); i++) {
        if(index === i){
            var tabTitle = document.getElementById('tab-title-' + index);
            tabTitle.style.background="#f3f3f3 url('form_includes/pressed.png') no-repeat right top"
            tabTitle.style.borderBottom = "0px";
            var tabSheet = document.getElementById('tab-sheet-' + index);
            tabSheet.style.display = "block";
        }else{
            var tabTitle = document.getElementById('tab-title-' + i);
            tabTitle.style.backgroundColor = "";
            tabTitle.style.borderBottom = "";
            var tabSheet = document.getElementById('tab-sheet-' + i);
            tabSheet.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Check in this way..

It will work fine!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this:you can change the src of img tag.**Edited**

```
<script>
function changeSrc(el) {

    el.src = "home.png";

}
</script>
<div>
<img src="School.png" onclick="changeSrc(this)" alt="" /></div>
```

or you can do this on click:

```
 tabTitle.style.backgroundImage = "url("+newImage+")";
```

Comment: then using your method only change background img src.